# uninitialized constant Users in Login facebook rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise

I am developing an app in Rails that will be integrated with facebook at the beginning of the session, but as I test the code, I get the following error.
`uninitialized constant Users`
I'm using Devise and omniauth-facebook

devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "App ID", "App Secret", callback_url: "http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback"
```

model/User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
   :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :omniauthable, 
   omniauth_providers: %i[facebook]
end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }
root 'main#home'
```

I am using rails in its latest version (5.2.1) and ruby ​​`2.5.1`

with this code you should already establish a connection

Comment: Just guessing, but should it be `devise_for :user`?